# I need to write a code that takes input(sentences) from user and stops at @

Tags: c++, visual-c++

As i said i need to write this code as my hw however i need to write this in while loop because we dont know how big will user write their sentences or how many sentences they will write. It is going to be a paragraph

```
string word;
string parag;
while (cin >> word)
{
    parag += word;
    for ( unsigned int k = 0; k < parag.length(); k++ )
    {
        if (parag.at(k) == '@')
        break;
    }
}
```

I know there are problems here but it wont stop even if i wrote "@". I dont know what to do i am just a beginner.

Comment: This is where you would want to use `getline`.

Comment: break only exits the for loop, not the while loop.

Comment: getline would work? Because its a little weird hw user could write sentences that finishes in next line. About break, how can i make it for while loop. I need to stop taking inputs when program sees "@" or program needs to read only before "@"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do

{
    parag = "";

cin >> word;

while (word != "@")
{   
    parag += word + " ";
    cin >> word;

}
parag = parag.substr (0, parag.length()-1); //Takes all characters but "@" at the end

ToLower(parag); //This code is in header file that our teacher gave us. Makes all characters lower case in order to make our code "case insensitive".

}while ( ( CheckInput(parag) ) ); // This checks inputs(obviously) if inputs are correctly entered.
```

This is what i wrote after going to class and learning about do-while loop if anyone interested. Program will take infinite "cin" to create a paragraph. About why getline(cin, parag) wouldn't work user could write something like this

"Roses are red

Violets are blue. @"

As you see sentence is not in the same line and getline takes only one line as inputs. And best part is (pls dont judge i am a beginner) with "do" i can say something like this if the input is wrong. "Please enter your input again" and i can take inputs without closing my program till all inputs are right.

Rest my homework is about taking paragraph from user. Dividing paragraph to sentences as user inputs (with finding dots). Reversing all the sentences, asking user to write reverse sentences and compare those inputs with programs to see if user give reverse sentences all correctly and if not say how many mistakes did user do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have the need to exit the program on reading the @ character... But this is how you read a sentence, hope this helps.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>

 using std::cin;
 using std::cout;
 using std::string;
 using std::getline;
 //You could do using namespace std, but that uses a lot more methods and functions 
 //that you don't need.

 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
         string parag;

         cout << "Enter your sentence here: ";
         getline(cin, parag); //Get the input until the user enters a newline. 
                             //usually via pressing enter.
         cout << "\nYou entered: " << parag; //The newline escape sequence is \n
         cin.ignore(); //Pause the program until newline is received.
 }
```

**Example output**

```
 $ ./OutputParag.exe
 Enter your sentence here: My input string is a sentence.

 You entered: My input string is a sentence.
```

Comment: My reason for questioning the use of ending on @ character is this: since in your code the user is never instructed to input the @ character to end the program, what happens if they never input a @ character? Your program will loop indefinitely, and the only reason you specify for doing so is that you don't know when your paragraph will end, thought I'd clear that up real quick.

Comment: That is what homework wants. I wrote a do-while loop and yes i need to make an infinite loop if user never input a @. And i now how to get input from a user thx for that tho :)